# How to put keyboard shortcut in context menu in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, shortcut

I want to put in context menu "**Toggle outlining expansion**" which is under menu:

`Edit->Outlining->Toggle outlining expansion`

but when I go to:

`Tools->Customize->Commands->Context menu->Edit context menu->Add command`

I can't find it on Edit menu "Toggle outlining expansion".

Why?

Probably cause it's now just command it is macro.

So now my question is what should I do to put those macro inside of context menu, it have shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

**How to put those keyboard shortcut inside context menu?**

Answer (score 0):

I solve problem with recording "Toogle outlining expansion", and than calling those new macro from customize.

Steps:

1. Start record macro with shortcut **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>**
2. Start your shortcut (in this case "Toogle outlining expansion") **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>**
3. Stop recording macro **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>**
4. On Macro explorer save those new macro **Macro explorer->Save**
5. Open Customize file to load macro **Tools->Customize->Commands->Context menu->Macro->"name_of_your_macro"**

In saved macro code look like this

```
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics
Public Module RecordingModule
    Sub TemporaryMacro()
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")
    End Sub
End Module
```